# How to do center align div content

Tags: html

I have div content which come after span label. The div content is 200+ char and after 150 char the next line starts and its starts from left but i want its should start from exact below of the line its started.

I have tried break(br) and text align center and tried white space \r\n and padding, nothing seems working.

please find the content and div code of the element below.

[label and div content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WZ9h.jpg)

[label and div code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElUMm.jpg)

second line should start from exact below of the line its started.

Comment: Could you please share your used css? I think you add some float to the content-class?

Comment: I am new to this project. I mean I have worked in jsp and HTML. here client are using xml and xstl and dojo js. kind of old tech. I am getting many answers but don't know which file I even have to edit to achieve that. hope you know my feel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex in your container. It will place the div after the span.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}
.label{
  width: 200px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="label">Adress: </span>
  <div class="content">wkejrkwghjkwgjwrgbkjwrgrwjg rweguherg ergouie rgoeurg ergouiherg erguherg ewrogherg erogher goerg ewrgieug ewrg wrgrwjg rweguherg ergouie rgoeurg ergouiherg erguherg ewroghergwrgrwjg rweguherg ergouie rgoeurg ergouiherg erguherg ewrogherg</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set display to `flex` and add `justify-content:center` on the divs CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```css
div.text {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 10% 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
<span>Address</span>
<div>
kjsdfhkjsdfhs dkfjhs djhfs kdjfkshjd fkjhsd kjhsdkfj sdkjf skdjhf ksjdhf kjsdh fkjhsdfkj sdkjfh skjdhf ksjdfk jsdkfhs dkjfhs kdjfskjdf ksjdhf ksjdhf ksjhdfkjshd fkjshdf kjsdkfj skdjfh skjdhf ksjdhf ksjdhf jshdfk jdsfkj skdjf skjdfh kjsdhfk jshdf kjhsdkfj hsdkjf skjdhf ksjdhf sdfksdfkjsd kjfhsdkjfh 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try the below code.

```css
.flex-box{
display:flex;
}
.flex-box span{
width: 150px;
}
.flex-box > div{
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box">
  <span>Adress: </span>
  <div>customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer customer </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a div with center align text. You can use it simply.

```css
div.center-align {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-align">
  This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.This is a test text.
<div>
```